# App page freezes for logged in user when performing meteor reset

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

When I have active Meteor login token and perform a DB drop with `meteor reset`, app page freezes badly on reload. It feels like the page keeps loading, though there is nothing on the page I can interact with. Browser console hangs as well. Tested on Chrome and Firefox, facing same behavior.
But when I try to remove cache for the app domain (through browser settings, as dev tools are unconscious), everything becomes okay, I get redirected to a login page (as provided in my route config) and browser console has the following message: `You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again`.
This is my Iron Router global onBeforeAction hook:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {

document.documentElement.className = 'gt-ie8 gt-ie9';

var currentUser = Meteor.user(),
    currentRoute = this.route.getName(),
    routeOptions = {},
    userRoles,
    userCompany, userTeam,
    allowedRoutes;

// prevent not logged in user from visiting the app
// console.log(this.next);
if (!currentUser) {
  this.redirect('login');
  // return;
} else {

  userRoles = currentUser.roles;

  userRoles = userRoles.length ? userRoles : ['member'];
  userCompany = currentUser.companyId || null;
  userTeam = currentUser.teamId || null;

  // get current user allowed routes (for highest role)
  allowedRoutes = _.filter(SW.roles, function (appRoute, index) {
    return userRoles.indexOf(index) > -1;
  });
  allowedRoutes = allowedRoutes && allowedRoutes.length ? allowedRoutes[0].routes : [];

  // if not all routes are allowed
  if (allowedRoutes.indexOf('*') === -1) {
    // restrict if route is not allowed
    if (!allowedRoutes.length || allowedRoutes.indexOf(currentRoute) === -1) {
      this.redirect('member.self');
    }
  }

}

this.next();

}, {
  except: ['enroll', 'login', 'logout']
});
```

I need to mention as well that this is very weird slippy issue that happens on production server far more often than when performing local testing.

Comment: You're using `meteor reset` on a production server? The problem is that this shuts down the Meteor server, disconnecting any users. If you update the code and let Meteor hot-reload as normal, this shouldn't happen unless the hot-reload times out.

Comment: @sbking I'm using `meteor reset` locally, and it happens time of the time in that case. Though on production there is a script that drops database after deployment, and it tends to appear more often there. After some changes I have to perform database drop, and this where the issue comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be gone with the latest Meteor update (1.0.2.1). Though, it may be because of [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/LTO2n5D1bxY/J5EnVpJo0rAJ) with Fast Render (fixed in 2.1.0), which I'm using on my project.